# Is using undefined as a value in object definition a good practice?

Tags: javascript, json, object, undefined, eslint

**tl;dr:** Is it a good practice to use `undefined` as a value or should I avoid it and try with another aproach?

I have an object which I use as a schema for my two functions `createUser()` and `updateUser()` and based on what values I need, I reconfigure it.

For `updateUser()` I need to send only the keys user entered in a form so the only way I know of, without changing the structure of the object manually, is to set the values to `undefined`.

```
// d is passed as argument

const args = {
  variables: {
    where: {id: "someValue"},
    data: {
      username: d.username || undefined,
      password: d.password || undefined,
      role: d.role || undefined,
    },
  },
};
```

Now if I have entered only `username`, my object will be

```
variables: {
  where: { id: "someValue"}, 
  data: { username: "anotherValue" }
}
```

I have given it a second thought after `ESLint` gave me a warning `"Unexpected use of undefined."`

**NOTE** I can't send empty values to API. It has to have either value or not send the key at all.

Comment: If you need to send `undefined`, what does it matter what ESLint says?

Comment: @ScottHunter or whoever else, would it be better to use `null`?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I can't do it with null, because the object will be sent with all the keys with values `null`, and I wan't to send only keys I changed.

Comment: it's up to you what you want to use, side note: why are you doing `|| undefined`? I think that if `d.username` (or any other `d.prop`) is undefined, it will be undefined anyway? I'd just do `d.username` and `d.password` etc... unless if you have some logical default value like `d.username || generateRandomUsername()`

Comment: @duxfox-- I have updated the question

Comment: @NinaScholz I use the object for 2 different functions, so based on `props` I get, I structure the `args`. Read the update please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to determine what **good** is and isn't, because it's always all about the needs and preferences of the client and your teammates.

The very simple and short answer to the question is: yes. `undefined` is a valid value and if this would be an evidently bad practice, then the language would not allow that value to be assigned. However, it's important to make sure that you do not duplicate your values. Taking a look at this object

```
{
  variables: {
    where: {id: "someValue"},
    data: {
      username: d.username || undefined,
      password: d.password || undefined,
      role: d.role || undefined,
    },
  },
};
```

we see that you repeat the same idea over and over again. Instead, you would do better to implement something like this:

```
function nicify(object) {
    for (var key in object) {
        if (!object[key]) object[key] = undefined;
        else if ((typeof(object[key]) === "object") || (Array.isArray(object[key]))) {
            nicify(object[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

the `function` above recursively does what you wanted to do with your attributes. This will be very helpful if you have many attributes and/or many use-cases. Also, if you consistently have the pattern of having a source object as in your example, then you can implement something like this:

```
function fillBySource(object, source) {
    for (var key in source) {
        object[key] = source[key] || undefined;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const args = {
  variables: {
    where: {id: "someValue"},
    data: {
      username: d.username || "",
      password: d.password || "",
      role: d.role || "",
    },
  },
};
```

It makes more sense to use empty values instead of keeping them undefined, or you can use `null`.

```
So, that your API contracts won't get violated.
```

Comment: I can't do it with null, because the object will be sent with all the keys with values `null`, and I wan't to send only keys I changed. Structure with your answer would be ```data: { username: "someValue , password: "", role: ""}``` and I want it "data: ```{username: "someValue}```

Comment: You can resend the entire object with all values with an extra array containing the keys which got modified. Not sending the key is never a solution if you are planning to use same endpoint for all use-cases.

Comment: My API wants to change everything that is sent through `data: {}` and that's why I can't send empty values.

Answer (score 2):

I think `|| null` or `|| ''` are better practise, if you `JSON.stringify()` to exchange data with a server or something nothing in the JSON tell you that a `username` and a `password` should be present in the `data` prop. You can see that in the following eg :

```js
function test(username, password, role) {
  const args = {
    variables: {
      where: {id: "someValue"},
      data: {
        username: username || undefined,
        password: password || undefined,
        role: role || undefined,
      },
    },
  };
  return JSON.stringify(args);
}

let json = test();

console.log(json);
```

Comment: yep I wanted to take the same code to prove that's a good practise

Answer (score 0):

To my best of knowledge, you should not assign undefined the way you are currently doing it, because if `d.username` in the code is not set, then it's value is already `undefined`.

Usually the use case for assigning `undefined` is when a variable is initially set, but you want to unset/reset it as if the value was never set in the first place.

Comment: I don't know what of the keys will be available when user enters the form. Sometimes he might change all of the available ```username, password, role``` and sometimes only one of them.

Comment: One way I achieve that in the past is by filtering out the keys with empty values in the object before sending it as data. It may be a little bit of work but I think it's safer.

Comment: This answer is not accurate. `||` is boolean operator so if there is a falsy value on the left side, right side is "returned". So `undefined` will be assigned even for null, 0, "",... You are not wrong, but you literaly tell to remove that `|| undefined` which change original behavior.

Comment: @Hookyns, I get your point, but then, the question is about form input values (if I understand correctly), so it's definitely not possible to enter null (not "null" as string) or  "" in the input field, and of course 0 is a valid input (unless otherwise stated). so if the input is not specified, then it is already undefined  or "" (which is suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58378779/10562007). My point here is just that assigning undefined is indeed an unexpected behaviour as marked by the linter.